# FFmpeg convert original audio into three different ones

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

I want to convert the audio of the video file, which is in DTS format, to three different types of AC3, one 640K, the second 448K and the last one 192K.
The DTS will be removed, and the video will be just copied. The container will remain the same.

I have tried this so far

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -ab 640k -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="640" -c:a:1 ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -ab 448k -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="448" -c:a:2 ac3 -b:a 192k -center_mixlev 0.707 -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -metadata:s:a:2 title="192" output.mkv
```

and

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -ab 640k -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="640" -map 0:a -c:a:1 ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -ab 448k -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="448" -map 0:a -c:a:2 ac3 -b:a 192k -center_mixlev 0.707 -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -metadata:s:a:2 title="192" output.mkv
```

But the resulting file has all the three audios in AC3 format, but 192K (all of them)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -b:a:0 640k -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="640" -b:a:1 448k -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="448" -b:a:2 192k -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -metadata:s:a:2 title="192" output.mkv
```

Since the audio encoder for all three streams is the same, you need only specify it once. But the stream specifiers for the audio bitrate should be fully qualified, else the last value set (192k) will be used for each encoding.

Comment: ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -center_mixlev 0.707 -b:a:0 640k  -af "pan=5.1(side)|FL=0.90*FL|FR=0.90*FR|FC=0.90FC|LFE=LFE|SL=0.90*SL|SR=0.90*SR" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="640" -b:a:1 448k  -af "pan=5.1(side)|FL=0.50*FL|FR=0.50*FR|FC=0.50FC|LFE=LFE|SL=0.50*SL|SR=0.50*SR" -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="448" -b:a:2 192k  -af "pan=5.1(side)|FL=0.10*FL|FR=0.10*FR|FC=0.10FC|LFE=LFE|SL=0.10*SL|SR=0.10*SR" -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -metadata:s:a:2 title="192" output.mkv Thx tried in here,takes only last

Comment: line of parameters, resulting file has all audios with these parameters applied -af "pan=5.1(side)|FL=0.10*FL|FR=0.10*FR|FC=0.10FC|LFE=LFE|SL=0.10*SL|SR=0.10*SR" I accepted your answer, it was perfect!, but in case of more parameters, don't know how to do it.

Comment: Instead of -af, use `-filter:a:0`..etc for stream-specific filtering.